# What is the difference between assignment, \setlength and \renewcommand when changing a variable?

Tags: macros, lengths

I want to set the `\extrarowheight` to `0.5ex`. I find the following three ways are all applicable.

```
\extrarowheight = 0.5ex
\setlength{\extrarowheight}{0.5ex}
\renewcommand{\extrarowheight}{0.5ex}
```

Just out of curiosity, which way is the canonical one?

Comment: One is setting it the tex way, one is using the latex way, one is more or less just wrong.

Comment: @Johannes_B I beg to differ. `\arraystretch` can only be changed by `\renewcommand` since `\arraystretch` is implemented as a macro rather than a variable.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments, the first version is the TeX version of assignments, the second version is the LaTeX version of assigning values to variables. Both usually yield the same result, as the second one is based on the first.

The second version is less error-prone, though, because it's equivalent to `\extrarowheight=0.5ex\relax` which prevents the parser from accidentally mistaking extra characters after the assignment to be part of the new value.

Note however, that the third version is *not* equivalent to the other two, and wrong in that sense. It doesn't do a variable assignment but redefines `\extrarowheight` to be a macro which expands to the token sequence `0.5ex`. You can see the difference when you try the following:

```
\setlength{\extrarowheight}{0.5ex}
\show\extrarowheight
```

outputs

> `\extrarowheight=\dimen104.`

while

```
\renewcommand{\extrarowheight}{0.5ex}
\show\extrarowheight
```

outputs

> `\extrarowheight=\long macro:`
>   `->0.5ex.`

In some cases the use of that macro will still yield the same result as the use of the variable, but as soon as you try to set the variable the correct way, the problem becomes apparent:

```
\renewcommand{\extrarowheight}{0.5ex}
\setlength{\extrarowheight}{1.0ex}
```

prints `0.5ex1.0ex` instead of doing an assignment.

Comment: Good answer. Note that `\setlength` and others can be extended by package like [calc](https://ctan.org/pkg/calc) to handle simple equations, e.g. `\setlength{\somelength}{\baselineskip + .5ex}`. Then it is not equivialent to the TeX assignment anymore.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed description. By the way, is `\extrarowheight 0.5ex` also legitimate?

Comment: Note that standard LaTeX `\arraystretch` is implemented as a macro. Thus it is not a variable and the "conceptual" assignment to it can only be achieved by `\renewcommand`. Actually, this is the origin for my question – people use `\renewcommand` for `\arraystretch` while `\setlength` for `\extrarowheight`.

Comment: @eli People use different things because things are implemented differently. You cannot use everyting everywhere. So the simple answer would be: use the right tool for the job. Not everything can be fixed by whacking it with a hammer.

Comment: @Johannes Agree! The motivation for this question is to do things right. Apparently I did not realize the difference between `\arraystretch` and `\extrarowheight` when asking this question.

Comment: @Eli4ph Yes, the `=` isn't even necessary there. The syntax for the "assignment operator" would look like `[ ]*=?[ ]*` as a regular expression.